# Python Script run from C# leaves Python exe running in background eating memory

Tags: python, c#, process

I am developing a C# ASP.Net Service that constantly reads GPIO on raspberry pis. This reads pins for inputs and also fires pins for outputs. I have the call working but my problem is I call the Python scripts every .5 seconds when needed. e.g the read input will be called every .5 second but the outputs will only fire when required. My problem is that each call starts a new instance of Python.exe and it does not close them when the script is run. I have tried all kinds of exits from the python script as well as some from the C# eg. process.Kill() but nothing is killing the Python exe. Attached is an image of the task manager to show the issue. Below I will add in the code I am using to call the python script and the read input script to show the python script I am calling. I have left some comments in so you can see what I have previously tried. Thanks

[image]

Code to call Python Script:

```
String exePath = SystemSettingDB.GetSettingValue("Python Executbale Path");
string holdPath = SystemSettingDB.GetSettingValue("Door Open Script Path");

var open = new ProcessStartInfo();

open.FileName = exePath;

var controllerIP = _controllerIP;

open.Arguments = $"\"{holdPath}\" \"{controllerIP}\" \"{_pin}\"";


open.UseShellExecute = false;
open.CreateNoWindow = true;
open.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
open.RedirectStandardError = true;

var process = Process.Start(open);


if (process != null)
{
     process.Kill();
     return true;
}
```

Python Script to read Inputs

```
import sys

import os
from time import sleep

os.environ["PIGPIO_PORT"] = "8888"
os.environ["GPIOZERO_PIN_FACTORY"] = "pigpio"
from gpiozero import LED

os.environ["PIGPIO_ADDR"] = sys.argv[1]
gpio_pin = sys.argv[2] 

door = LED(gpio_pin)

door._read()
print(door.value)

sys.exit(0)
#os._exit(-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
1. Download PSTools from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pskill
2. Write the following code:

```
>       public static void killPython()
    {
        var killPython = new ProcessStartInfo();
        killPython.FileName = @"\Your_PSTools_Path\pskill.exe";
        //-t Kill the process and its descendants. 
        killPython.Arguments = "-t PID"; //process PID from Task Manager
        Process.Start(killPython);
    }
```

3. Run your code as administrator

Comment: John, thanks for the suggestion. I will keep it in mind but I was hoping for something cleaner that would kill the process which was just started as if I kill all processes I will kill some active python.exe as well.